# How to build pyinstaller spec files from python code

Tags: python, pyinstaller

Does anybody know how to generate pyinstaller spec files from python code, preferably without calling the `makespec.main` function in the pyinstaller library?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways that I can think of off the top of my head. Why are you opposed to using the `makespec.main` function? That is my preferred way of doing it, as its very easy to pass certain specs and create a custom spec file. The other way would be to utilize the script `pyi-makespec` via a subprocess. This is a little silly though and the `makespec.main` function is much easier to implement in my eyes. For example

```py
import subprocess

subprocess.run(['pyi-makespec', <YOUR RUN SCRIPT>, extra specs], shell=True)
```

Comment: Thanks, This is what I was looking for. I'd prefer to not use `makespec.main` just in case the module structure changes - I'm using this for a github project.

Comment: Great glad it helped. If it solved your question, please select it with the checkmark to mark it as solved.

Comment: It kinda solved it - but I'm going to wait a week or so to see if any answers solve it better.